# vim filter/delete a line

Tags: regex, vim, filter

We have a tyfoons.txt file which contains several information attributes of real typhoons in the past. One line from the file is as follows:

```
Name-identification number- wind - duration - beginning date - ending date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mary ( North ) − 1977.21 − 945 − 12 Days 18 Hours − 1977−12−21 00:00 − 1978−01−02 18:00
```

Now I have to filter out the typhoons span 2 different years, like the example above being for 1977 and 1978.
We consider that a typhoon doesn't exist longer than 30 days.

How can I filter those lines out of the file?

Comment: The example you gave doesn't last more than 30 days, even though it crosses a year boundary.  Which is the more relevant requirement, the year changing or the duration lasting more than 30 days?

Comment: yeah, but a typhoon can start at the 20th of december and end the second of januari, i tried to do something like that but i keep getting error messages, pattern not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive solution (just checking whether a year is crossed) could be achieved using the [`:g`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Ag) command.

E.g., delete any line which doesn't have the same year for start and end

```
:g!/\(\d\{4}\)−\d\d−\d\d \d\d:\d\d − \1−\d\d−\d\d \d\d:\d\d$/d
```

The relevant parts here are re-using the matched year in the first date (`\(\d\{4\}\)`) as the year in the second data (`\1`).  `:g!/{pat}/{cmd}` executes `{cmd}` for every line that doesn't match `{pat}`, so when the years differ, the [`:d`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Ad) command is run and deletes that line.

Performing more complex checks (within a 30 day window) would probably be better achieved by writing a function that pulls apart the relevant data from the line and does the necessary calculations.  A basic skeleton would be:

```
function DeleteInvalidDateRanges()
    " matchlist() returns a list of the entire string that matched and all matched groups
    " so slicing the list to extract items 1-4 gives a list of [year, month, date, time]
    let dateTime1 = matchlist(getline('.'), '\(\d\{4}\)−\(\d\d\)−\(\d\d\) \(\d\d:\d\d\)', 0, 1)[1:4]
    let dateTime2 = matchlist(getline('.'), '\(\d\{4}\)−\(\d\d\)−\(\d\d\) \(\d\d:\d\d\)', 0, 2)[1:4]
    if MoreThan30Days(dateTime1, dateTime2)
        delete
    endif
endfunction
:%call DeleteInvalidDateRanges()
```

For more information on scripting in Vim, you can see the [relevant part](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html) of the [user guide](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_toc.txt.html).

---

Simply deleting any lines which have a start month of 12 and end month of 01 is a slight change to the initial "different years" example.

```
:g/\d\{4}−12−\d\d \d\d:\d\d − \d\{4}−01−\d\d \d\d:\d\d$/d
```

Comment: we've never seen such construction, so i doubt that this is the way we have to solve it, I think we must delete al the lines that does't have the date year-12-day(beginning) or year-01-day(ending); This was my solution but it doesn't work: :g/(.*-12-.* .*:.*)-(.*-01-.* .*:.*)/d, this should delete all the lines that have a yearbound, so it should also be reversed

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `we've never seen such construction`.  Do you mean you haven't seen Vim commands like this?  If so, I don't see how that's relevant to whether this does what you're requesting.  At any rate, changing my simple `:g` example to only look for a starting month of 12 and ending month of 01 is a basic transformation of what's already there.  I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @fangio You need to use `\(\)` to perform groupings.  `()` matches the literal characters in Vim's regex, but since you're not actually using the groups, just don't use them.

Comment: Yeah, i am a student and we've only seen constructions like :1,$s/... and so on, we've never used programming language in vim.

Comment: I now know that there are 3 such lines but how can i get the oposite of this? :2,$g/.*-12-.* .*:.*-.*-01-.* .*:.*/d                  I mean delete not 12 and not 01

Comment: If you mean `delete all lines which do not match this pattern`, then that's what `:g!` (as I used in my first example) or the more common alternative `:v` does.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I want, sorry that I was bothering you with this actually stupid question, I forgot some crucial regex constructions. So thank you and a bit late but Happy Newyear :)